# String abbreviation techniques in R

Tags: r

How do I convert "Tony Stark" to "T. Stark" in R using String Manipulation techniques. I know I have to use abbreviation technique, but I am not able to get the desired output.

```
names_abb <- abbreviate(names,2,dot = TRUE)
names_abb
```

Output I am getting is

```
 Bruce Wayne   Tony Stark Peter Parker   Clark Kent 
       "BW."        "TS."        "PP."        "CK."
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
vec <- c('Tony Stark', 'Bruce Wayne', 'Clark Kent')
str_c(substring(vec, 1, 1), '. ', gsub('([A-z]+)\\s([A-z]+)', '\\2', vec))
[1] "T. Stark" "B. Wayne" "C. Kent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use `strsplit`:

```
x <- 'Tony Stark'

paste0(substr(strsplit(x, split = ' ', fixed = T)[[1]][1], 1, 1),
      '. ',
      strsplit(x, split = ' ', fixed = T)[[1]][2])



#[1] "T. Stark"
```

Answer (score 0):

For a `stringr` solution, you could try the following:

```
test_string <- c("Tony Stark", "Nick Fury")

stringr::str_replace(test_string, ".+\\s", stringr::str_c(str_sub(test_string, start = 1L, end = 1L), ". "))
```